# Journey Builder - Can subscribers be added to any point other than the beginning of a journey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

We are planning to build a very extensive journey that will require our team to add subscribers to the journey. We'd prefer that the new subscribers that are added begin their journey in sync with others in the journey already. (Content is time sensitive) Is that possible within Journey Builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will advocate for following the advice of Jonas, where instead of one long journey, you would use e.g. a series of automations, selecting the audience with SQL Query, and having an Email Send triggered by Automation Studio.

If you for some reason insist to use Journey Builder, you might want to use a combination of multiple [Wait Until Date Activities](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sf.mc_jb_wait_until_a_specific_date.htm&language=en_US), as well as date based [Decision Splits](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_use_decision_splits.htm&type=5):

Your journey will look something like this:
[image]

So, what is going on? Let's take it step by step. Firstly, let's assume the entry event would be an API call. But it can basically be anything.

First activity in the journey is a Contact Update, which requires a sendable data extension with two fields: Contact Key and Entry Date. This should be created before you can configure this activity. Furthermore, the data extension needs to be added to an attribute group in Data Designer, so it can be used for decision splits later on.

You will configure the activity to populate the Entry Date field with current date and time, as below:
[image]

Next, we will add a decision split, looking at Contact Data and your newly created Attribute Group:
[image]

This should check, whether the entry date is before the planned send date of your first email (assuming Dec. 6th). If the contact has entered the journey before, we are proceeding to the wait step, which will hold on to the contact until the expected send date of your first email:
[image]

If your contact has entered the journey later than on Dec 6th, both the wait step and the email activity will be bypassed.

Your next email activity will be "wrapped" with a similar combination of Decision Split and Wait until, just with a different date. Let's assume you want to send email 2 on the 13th of December, then your Decision Split should check if your contact has entered the journey earlier than this. If so, this person will proceed to the wait step, and if not (entering on e.g. the 14th of December) both the Wait step and the Email activity will be bypassed.

And you can continue creating as many activities along the line, and these can both be email steps, app push, SMS or anything else you like.

Comment: You're amazing! Thank you, Lukas!

Answer (score 0):

I am, by no means, the definitive source of truth for this, but I just tried to create a journey with more than 1 entry source and I could not.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I figured..

Answer (score 0):

What are you are trying is not possible.

So when planning long journeys, do not fall into the (tempting) trap of making it all ONE journey. Identify the touchpoints (emails,...) inside the journey and split the journey into several smaller ones (at best one step only) combined with a solid logging setup that can help your follow up selections.

Which will allow you to:

- inject anywhere
- test any part independently of wait steps or other parts
- make changes anywhere independently